# How to import one from two handmade modules depending on some parameters

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a question. I am importing handmade module "agent" into different module in the same project in pycharm. But I have two versions of "agent" module (let's say agent1 and agent2). How to run project once with first and once with the second version? Can I make some parameter which will be chosen just before running code and it will change agent1 to agent2 and other way? 
I use pycharm.

Answer (score 1):

```
if something:
    import agent1 as agent
else:
    import agent2 as agent
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put an import after and `if` statement

```
if condition_1:
    from module import agent1
else:
    from module import agent2
```